# Как сгенерировать компонент в конкретную папку c помощью angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Я использую angular-cli 7.0.3
Есть модуль `src/app/schemas`.
Нужно создать в нем компонент schema. Использую следующую команду:

```
ng generate component schema --module=schemas
```

Но файлы создаются в папке с модулем, следующим образом:

```
src/app/schemas/schema.component.ts.
```

Компонентов будет несколько и я бы хотел, чтобы они находились в отдельных папках внутри модуля, вот так:

```
src/app/schemas/schema/schema.component.ts
```

Как сгенерировать новый компонент schema в папку schema в модуле schemas используя angular-cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите путь:

```
ng g c 'schemas/schema' --module=schemas
```